# how to hide sorting of specific column in datatable?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I am using datatable API. Here, I want to hide sorting arrows for some specific columns. How do I do that ?

I tried this code but didn't work.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 }
  ]
});
```

Comment: change 'datatable' tag to 'jquery-datatables' please.

Comment: I updated the answer to correct the tags. Also note that datatables tag is remapped to jquery-datatables tag ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/datatables/synonyms)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to target a specific column, multiple columns, or all columns, use the `aTargets` property instead your `"targets"`. The `aTargets` property is an **array** to target one of your columns and it can be:

- `aTargets : [0]` - first column from the left
- `aTargets : [1]` - second column, etc...
- `aTargets: ['_all']` - select all columns

So if you want to hide sorting arrow for let's say **first column**, use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        aoColumnDefs : [ {
           orderable : false, aTargets : [0]        
        }],
        order: [] 
    } );
} );
```

During initialization in example we don't want to apply ordering, so we set order property empty:

```
order: []
```

I choose one table from [datatables examples](https://datatables.net/examples/) and put all this in working example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tj61396k/)